# Rails 3 Routing: Resources and Paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have the following Route in my Rails app:

```
resources :settings, :path => :account, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

This creates the following:

```
edit_setting GET    /account/:id/edit(.:format) settings#edit
setting PUT    /account/:id(.:format) settings#update
```

How do I write it so the `:id` is omitted?

So a user can just access `/account/edit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most straightforward way to do it, and keep you close to the rails conventions:

```
match 'account/edit'  => 'accounts#edit',   :as => 'edit_account',  :via => :get
match 'accounts'      => 'accounts#update', :as => 'accounts',      :via => :put
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources for details, but I'm pretty sure `resource :settings, :path => :account, :only => [:edit, :update]` will work.